# Who was the guru of Vibhishana?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, guru

I found the following dialogues between Shri Hanuman and Vibhishana while going through Sundara Kand of [**Shri Ramcharit Manasa**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/ramacharitamanas/sundar745-804.pdf). And I came to know that Vibhishana is a true devotee of Lord Shri Rama and he was masterless going by the verses below. Because he was masterless, Lord Shri Rama graced him by sending Lord Hanuman ('the saint' in the verses).

> सुनहु पवनसुत रहनि हमारी। जिमि दसनन्हि महुँ जीभ बिचारी॥
>   तात कबहुँ मोहि जानि अनाथा। करिहहिं कृपा भानुकुल नाथा॥1॥
>   sunahu pavanasuta rahani hamåri, jimi dasananhi mahu jeebha bichari.
>   tåta kabahu mohi jåni anåthå, karihahi krupå bhånukula nåthå.1.
>
> तामस तनु कछु साधन नाहीं। प्रीत न पद सरोज मन माहीं॥
>   अब मोहि भा भरोस हनुमंता। बिनु हरिकृपा मिलहिं नहिं संता॥2॥
>   tåmasa tanu kachu sådhana nåhi, preeti na pada saroja mana måhi.
>   aba mohi bhå bharosa hanumantå, binu harikrupå milahi nahi santå.2.
>
> जौं रघुबीर अनुग्रह कीन्हा। तौ तुम्ह मोहि दरसु हठि दीन्हा॥
>   सुनहु बिभीषन प्रभु कै रीती। करहिं सदा सेवक पर प्रीति॥3॥
>   jau raghubira anugraha kinhå, tau tumha mohi darasu hathi dinhå.
>   sunahu bibhishana prabhu kai riti, karahi sadå sevaka para preeti.3.
>
> भावार्थ:-(विभीषणजी ने कहा-) हे पवनपुत्र! मेरी रहनी सुनो। मैं यहाँ वैसे ही रहता हूँ जैसे दाँतों के बीच में बेचारी जीभ। हे तात! मुझे अनाथ जानकर सूर्यकुल के नाथ श्री रामचंद्रजी क्या कभी मुझ पर कृपा करेंगे?॥1॥
>   तामसी (राक्षस) शरीर होने से साधन तो कुछ बनता नहीं और न मन में श्री रामचंद्रजी के चरणकमलों में प्रेम ही है, परंतु हे हनुमान्‌! अब मुझे विश्वास हो गया कि श्री रामजी की मुझ पर कृपा है, क्योंकि हरि की कृपा के बिना संत नहीं मिलते॥2॥श्री रघुवीर ने कृपा की है, तभी तो आपने मुझे हठ करके (अपनी ओर से) दर्शन दिए हैं। (हनुमान्‌जी ने कहा-) हे विभीषणजी! सुनिए, प्रभु की यही रीति है कि वे सेवक पर सदा ही प्रेम किया करते हैं॥3॥
>
> Hear, O son of the wind-god, how I am living here: my plight is similar to that of the poor tongue, that lives in the midst of the teeth. Will the Lord of the solar race, dear friend, ever show His grace to me, knowing me to be masterless? Endowed as I am with a sinful (demoniac) form, I am incapable of doing any Sådhana (striving for God Realization); and my heart cherishes no love for the Lord's lotus-feet. But I am now confident, Hanumån, that lord Råma will shower His grace on me; for one can never meet a saint without lor∂ Hari's grace. It is only because the Hero of Raghu's race has been kind to me that you have blessed me with your sight unsolicited.
>   Listen, Vibhisana: the Lord is ever affectionate to His servants; for such is His wont. Tell me what superior birth can I claim-a frivolous monkey vile in everyway, so much so that if anyone mentions our name early in the morning he is sure to go without any food that day.

**Does this mean Lord Hanuman is the spiritual guru of Vibhishana?**

Why I'm assuming this is because, God himself knows who needs a guru and sends a guru to his true devotee. Getting a guru only happens by God's grace. Actually, it is not the disciple who finds the guru, it is the guru who finds the disciple.

If Lord Hanuman is not the spiritual guru of Vibhishana then:

- Who was the guru of Vibhishana?
- Is there any reference available on this?

References :
 - [Astrojyoti](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/ramacharitamanas/sundar745-804.pdf)
 - [Webdunia](http://hindi.webdunia.com/religion/religion/hindu/ramcharitmanas/SunderKand/4.htm)

Comment: In Goswami Tulsidas's Ramcharitmanas, Lord Ram gave the preaching to Vibhishana which is known as Vibhishan Geeta.I thik this suggest Lord Ram was his Guru.